# ASIHTTPRequest + SBJSon iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest, sbjson

I am working with an application where I have to request a url and I get the response accordingly

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to request the URL 
here is my request

```
-(void)getTips {
    if ([CommonFunctions networkConnected]) {
        ShowNetworkActivityIndicator();
        NSString *strPhp = @"staticpage.php";
    NSString *strQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?static_id=3",GMS_URL,strPhp]];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strQuery]];
        NSLog(@"tips url %@",request.url);
        request.delegate = self;
        [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
}
```

These are my delegate methods

```
-(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

//    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//    NSLog(@"responseStr %@",responseStr);
    SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"json data %@",[json objectWithData:data]);
    NSMutableArray *marrData = [[json objectWithData:data] valueForKey:@"responseData"];
    if([[marrData valueForKey:@"result"] isEqualToString:@"failed"]){
        [CommonFunctions showAlertMessage:[marrData valueForKey:@"error"]];
    }
    HideNetworkActivityIndicator();
}
```

Here I get null data no matter whether I pass request methods GET or POST

When I check the same url in browser I get the response and a valid json from online json viewer

What are the possible reason that I am getting null data in the application

Comment: ASI network library is already discontinued. Try `AFNetworking`.

Comment: thnx shivan !! i replaced my code with AFNetworking and now everything is working nicely !

Answer (score 1):

Use requestFinished: delegate.. Please try this.

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSLog(@"response %@", [request responseString]);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting anything as responseString as well !